# Premium ASP.NET hosting

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I know there are a million ASP.NET hosting options, but what are the premium options if you have some money to spend and want maximum performance and uptime?  We currently use MaximumASP and they are generally great.  I know another good option is Rackspace.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?  This is one of those things that is hard to Google, because everyone calls their hosting option premium or professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say Rackspace is a good choice, but I use discountasp.net because I needed .NET 3.5 SP1 hosting with SQL 2008 and they delivered.

Comment: I use rackspace and they do pretty much what ever I ask of them. They won't have any problems hosting .NET 3.5 SP1 or SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Although they will not have problems to host what ever you ask, discountasp.net specializes in .NET/ASP tech. I haven't had problems with them, but as the OP says, everyone who has good experiences will call their hosting premium. 
Discountasp.net's control panel is awful, but it works. 
The whole discountasp.net web site is also awful and confusing.
But the hosting is ok so far. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want something between shared hosting and Rackspace dedicated, check out their newly acquired cloud offering.  I've been using it for a few months with a lot of success.

http://www.rackspacecloud.com/

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice would be to get a dedicated server, other than that I love: DiscountAsp.net as they always have the most up-to-date frameworks on their servers. Useful if your trying a new technology such as when MVC was in beta

Comment: I like DiscountAsp.net too, but I have to think at those low prices, you're sharing a machine with a lot of other websites.  What I'd personally love is a solution that's managed (so I don't have to be a sys admin), but where I get a dedicated server (or large portion of a server).

Answer (score 2):

I have used [SoftSysHosting](http://www.softsyshosting.com/) for a multitude of clients, and they have never let me down...plus, their Customer Support is excellent, accompanied with a Knowledge Base of FAQs.

Comment: wow, for only $42 a month with SQL2008 and .NET3.5 support, thats affordable for a developer.

Answer (score 2):

I use [ORCS Web](http://www.orcsweb.com/) for one of my sites. I've never had any problems with them in over 2 years. They asked me to fill in a survey a few months back asking what I thought of their support and I had to admit that I'd never really had to use them beyond the initial setup.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). AppHarbor provides sophisticated scaling and load balancing and a [catalog of great add-ons](https://appharbor.com/addons). We also provide tools to make it easier for developers to move their code onto the platform using their favourite revision control tool (Git is supported and the platform is integrated with Github, Bitbucket and Codeplex). Here's a good overview of How AppHarbor Works.

(Disclaimer, I'm co-founder of [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/))

Comment: Really interesting alternative to traditional hosting, but it looks very raw right now.  There's very little info on what you get in each plan, the complexities of a push from Subversion, etc.  I'll keep an eye on this as you develop it.

Comment: I think there are good ways to run Git and Subversion side by side: http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/ This blog post has more details on what the plans do: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/02/announcing-pricing

Answer (score 1):

Terremark.com

http://www.terremark.com

Managed Hosting and Enterprise Cloud options.